# Why are my required libs not being converted from ES6 to ES5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am writing a `react` app where I `require` in another lib that is using `ES6` syntax.  Here is my code using the lib:

```
var React = require('react');
var Calendar = require('horario-calendar');

var appts = [];

React.render(<Calendar />, document.getElementById('calendar'));
```

`horario-calendar` is the third party app and it is full of `ES6` syntax.  I have a `gulp` task, that should `transpile` all the code to `ES6`.  Here is the task:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var to5 = require('6to5ify');

module.exports = function(gulp, config) {
    gulp.task('browserify', function() {
        browserify(config.app.src, {debug: true})
            .transform(to5)
            .transform(reactify)
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source(config.app.bundleName))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app.bundle));
    });
};
```

But it is not `transpile`ing by code that is `require`d in.  It is only `transpile`ing my code.  I still have `ES6` style imports all in the `horario-calendar`.  What do I need to do to `transpile` that code also?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using webpack instead of Browserify - you'll additionally enjoy the benefits of JSX hot loader. https://github.com/babel/6to5-loader worked flawlessly for me out of the box, though I did replace this:

```
{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: '6to5-loader'}
```

in their examples, to this:

```
{ test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: '6to5-loader'}
```

since I happened to only be using arrow functions in .jsx files, so look out for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this burden would rest with the third-party library, but if that is not an option, you could attempt to utilize [global transforms](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts):

> If opts.global is true, the transform will operate on ALL files,
>   despite whether they exist up a level in a node_modules/ directory.
>   Use global transforms cautiously and sparingly, since most of the time
>   an ordinary transform will suffice. You can also not configure global
>   transforms in a package.json like you can with ordinary transforms.
>
> Global transforms always run after any ordinary transforms have run.

So replacing `.transform(to5)` with `.transform({ global: true }, to5)`.

Also, 6to5 (now Babel) has built-in JSX support, so you shouldn't need Reactify.